# Python test fails printing dependency on local package

Tags: bazel

I thought that bazel runs tests in sandbox, but recently I got an error pointing to a local module `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py`. It it correct? How to make bazel run in a sandbox?

```
exec ${PAGER:-/usr/bin/less} "$0" || exit 1
Executing tests from //master:master_impl_test
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/agent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_agent/374e3bc824f25540df2be790dbb8f41e/sandbox/linux-sandbox/1/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/master/master_impl_test.runfiles/__main__/master/master_impl_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    from master import master_impl
  File "/home/agent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_agent/374e3bc824f25540df2be790dbb8f41e/sandbox/linux-sandbox/1/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/master/master_impl_test.runfiles/__main__/master/master_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
    from azure.cosmos import cosmos_client
  File "/home/agent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_agent/374e3bc824f25540df2be790dbb8f41e/sandbox/linux-sandbox/1/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/master/master_impl_test.runfiles/py_deps/pypi__azure_cosmos/azure/cosmos/cosmos_client.py", line 25, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/agent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_agent/374e3bc824f25540df2be790dbb8f41e/sandbox/linux-sandbox/1/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/master/master_impl_test.runfiles/py_deps/pypi__requests/requests/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/home/agent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_agent/374e3bc824f25540df2be790dbb8f41e/sandbox/linux-sandbox/1/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/master/master_impl_test.runfiles/py_deps/pypi__urllib3/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 675, in <module>
    _lib.Cryptography_HAS_TLSEXT_HOSTNAME, "SNI not available"
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'Cryptography_HAS_TLSEXT_HOSTNAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

Today my project's CI get this error. I fixed this problem in my project, just upgrading `pyOpenSSL` library to latest version.

Old requirements-file.txt:

> requests
> pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
> urllib3==1.25.3

New requirements-file.txt:

> cffi==1.14.4
> cryptography==3.3
> pycparser==2.20
> pyOpenSSL==20.0.0
> six==1.15.0
> urllib3==1.25.3

Comment: 1. Do you have listed `pyOpenSSL` twice with different versions? 2. Thanks for sharing solution, but my mine question was about lack of Bazel sandboxing.